# Stacked D3JS Bubble Chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, circle-pack

Hey I'm using D3JS as a chart library and I'm really interested in exploiting the cool features in the Bubble Chart. On the main [D3JS](http://d3js.org/) chart site the following Bubble Chart is used to compare two sets of data:

[image]

[Bubble Chart](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/09/06/us/politics/convention-word-counts.html).

I was wondering if anybody actually had any idea of how to create a bubble chart like this, I'm struggling to get it work past using a size variable.

I just really want to be able to compare two sets of data for example:

Hostnames (45,955,158) VS Active Sites (21,335,629)

The code I am using is below, I use JSON to retrieve my data, I'm a major newbie when it comes to js and even more so this jQuery library so would appreciate any help.

index.html

```
<div class="four columns browserstats2003">
            <h3>Browser Stats 2003</h3>

        </div>        
    <div class="four columns mobilephonestats">
       <h3>Smartphone Sales 2003</h3>
       <p>The first smartphone had not been released in 2003.</p>
               <div id=""></div>


    </div>
```

mobile.json

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Smartphone Sales", "size": 11111},
  {"name": "Smartphone Salesa", "size": 2111}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

js/js.js
// JavaScript Document

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        //  2003 bubble chart
            var diameter = 360,
                format = d3.format(",d"),
                color = d3.scale.category20c();

            var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
                .sort(null)
                .size([diameter, diameter])
                .padding(1.5);

            var svg = d3.select(".mobilephonestats").append("svg")
                .attr("width", diameter)
                .attr("height", diameter)
                .attr("class", "bubble");

            d3.json("mobile.json", function(error, root) {
              var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                  .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
                  .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
                .enter().append("g")
                  .attr("class", "node")
                  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

              node.append("title")
                  .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

              node.append("circle")
                  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
                  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

              node.append("text")
                  .attr("dy", ".3em")
                  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                  .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
            });

            // Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
            function classes(root) {
              var classes = [];

              function recurse(name, node) {
                if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
                else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
              }

              recurse(null, root);
              return {children: classes};
            }

            d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");

// end bubble year 

        });
```

Comment: Did you have a look at any of the other bubble chart examples?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes i did but none of the examples are like the ones i need

Comment: It looks to me like all you would have to do is fill the bubbles with a hard gradient. Oh and maybe have a force layout instead of the pack layout if you want to go for more or less exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

In the [example you provided](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/09/06/us/politics/convention-word-counts.html), he's definitely using a force layout, which is a bit more complicated that the Bubble Chart you're using. You'll have to take into consideration things like collisions and animation.

Why not just have a look at [the JavaScript he used](http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2012/09/04/convention-speeches/ac823b240e99920e91945dbec49f35b268c09c38/index.js) to generate it.

Jim Vallandingham wrote an extensive tutorial on [Bubble Clouds](http://vallandingham.me/building_a_bubble_cloud.html), which should get you started.

To create the split in the middle of the cirlce as a way of doing some form of data comparison, "clip-paths" are the way forward:

- Append two circles, one for each data-set.
- Append two clip-path, one for each data-set
- Append a rectange to each clip-path.
- Set the rectangle x attributes and width, which defines the position of the split in the middle. This has to be a function of the data.
- Crop the rectangles and circles

Here's the code:

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("a")
      .attr("class", "g-node")
      .call(force.drag);

  var democratEnter = nodeEnter.append("g")
      .attr("class", "g-democrat");

  democratEnter.append("clipPath") // clip-path to crop the rectangle
      .attr("id", function(d) { return "g-clip-democrat-" + d.id; })
    .append("rect");

  democratEnter.append("circle");

  var republicanEnter = nodeEnter.append("g")
      .attr("class", "g-republican");

  republicanEnter.append("clipPath") // Clip-path to crop the rectangle
     .attr("id", function(d) { return "g-clip-republican-" + d.id; })
     .append("rect");

  republicanEnter.append("circle");

  node.selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return -d.r - clipPadding; })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return 2 * d.r + 2 * clipPadding; });

  // Defining the x-attr and width of the rectangle, which effectively splits the circle
  node.select(".g-democrat rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return -d.r - clipPadding; }) 
      .attr("width", function(d) { return 2 * d.r * d.k + clipPadding; });

  node.select(".g-republican rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return -d.r + 2 * d.r * d.k; })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return 2 * d.r; });

  // Setting the clip-path to crop the circles
  node.select(".g-democrat circle")
      .attr("clip-path", function(d) { return d.k < 1 ? "url(#g-clip-democrat-" + d.id + ")" : null; });

  node.select(".g-republican circle")
      .attr("clip-path", function(d) { return d.k > 0 ? "url(#g-clip-republican-" + d.id + ")" : null; });
```

This should generate something like this:

```
<g class="g-democrat">
    <clipPath id="g-clip-democrat-43">
        <rect y="-63.36487389363757" height="126.72974778727514" x="-63.36487389363757" width="59.449375597303515">
        </rect>
    </clipPath>
    <circle clip-path="url(#g-clip-democrat-43)" r="59.36487389363757">
</circle></g>
<g class="g-republican">
    <clipPath id="g-clip-republican-43">
        <rect y="-63.36487389363757" height="126.72974778727514" x="-3.915498296334057" width="118.72974778727514">
        </rect>
    </clipPath>
    <circle clip-path="url(#g-clip-republican-43)" r="59.36487389363757">
</circle></g>
```